# In the U.S are judges, attorneys, physicians, teachers, professors, politicians, administrative officers liable for ordinary negligence?

Tags: united-states, employment, common-law, negligence, immunity

E.g can a judge be tried for mistrial because of ordinary negligence?

They are not employees or workers so that they could be reasonably absolved for ordinary negligence.

We expect employees to be obedient so they have no moral responsibility, if we held them liable we would harm the market people would be reluctutant to enter a contract of employeement.

In all these of judges etc cases they receive more than enough indenization for assuming responsibility.

By freeing them from ordinary negligence we are making them negligent.

Other than political economics why would the legislator free them from such responsibility?

Comment: Thought about moving to close this as too broad but answered instead. In general, however, try to focus your questions more narrowly. There are at least six different kinds of professions asked about in this question and the question does not specify liability for what kind of act as a result of ordinary negligence.

Comment: I have vote to close as too broad. The well-written answer by  @ohwilleke only makes clear the wide variety of legal and political issues included in this question. In addition, it includes incorrect assumptions, such as  "We expect employees to be obedient so they have no moral responsibility" there are cases where an employee has a moral and legal duty to disobey the instructions of an employer -- for example, when ordered to violate a law.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I am restricting the responsibility to instructions strictly related to their job. What the employer is expected to instruct their employee. They are employees only when putting their job through. In the rest of their lifes they are themselves. And I am also restricting the liability to ordinary negligence not even gross negligence. When they are ordered to violate a law(they actually foresee the consequences and deem them necessary to please their boss)  it is oblique intent.

Comment: @George Ntoulos I am not sure what you mean by "oblique intent" I have not encountered that term in legal writing. In any case the question as currently written does not include the restrictions mentioned in your comment. In any case the current rules vary by profession, and by circumstance, and employees may be held liable for various kinds of actions, even when following instructions in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In all these of judges etc cases they receive more than enough
>   indenization for assuming responsibility.
>
> By freeing them from ordinary negligence we are making them negligent.
>
> Other than political economics why would the legislator free them from
>   such responsibility?

Judges are precisely the ones rendering this question within scope of Law SE --not Politics SE-- insofar as they repeatedly cite cases like [*Parker v. State*, 337 Md. 271 (1995)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1995608337md2711593) to allege that:

> absolute immunity is needed to forestall endless collateral attacks on
>   judgments through civil actions against the judges themselves.

Under that pretext, the judicial system has become quite retrograde compared to how it was 4,000 years ago. Indeed, *judicial immunity* is the opposite of how the [Code of Hammurabi](http://www.general-intelligence.com/library/hr.pdf) in its fifth law addressed the problem of judicial incompetence:

> If a judge atry a case, reach a decision, and present his judgment in
>   writing; if later error shall appear in his decision, and it be
>   through his own fault, then he **shall pay twelve times the fine set by
>   him** in the case, and he shall **be publicly removed from the judge's
>   bench, and never again shall he sit there to render judgement**.

(emphasis added)

I usually get a cascade of downvotes (and I am called "abusive", and so forth) here on Law SE for pointing to uncomfortable truths about the judiciary, but you are right in that society makes judges negligent --at best-- by allowing absolute judicial immunity to remain in our system.

The problem goes beyond merely ordinary negligence. Nowadays the judiciary defends that

> absolute judicial immunity [...] applies regardless of the nature of
>   the tort and even where the suit against the judge alleges that he
>   acted in bad faith, maliciously or corruptly

*Parker*, *supra* at 284-285 (citations omitted), and many judges abuse that prerogative.

As an example of that judicial abuse, consider the matter of judge Lisa Gorcyca and her rage against the Tsimhoni siblings in year 2015. [This](http://www.deadlinedetroit.com/articles/17999/lengel_shameful_supreme_court_lets_judge_gorcyca_off_with_a_mere_censure) and [this](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/2018/07/larsen-in-scotus-big-no-no.html) are only two of many posts discussing the ultimate outcome of that aberration. Even though judge Gorcyca extorted, yelled at, and for 17 days jailed the Tsimhoni siblings, absolute judicial immunity would bar any civil action for all the Intentional Infliction of Emotional Distress to which these three innocent siblings were subjected by judge Gorcyca.

Judicial immunity supposedly encompasses judicial acts only, but the fact is that it significantly extends to non-judicial acts as well. Consider the matter of [judge Gregg Iddings](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inmico20170707234), who sexually harassed his secretary from 2012 to 2015.

Pretty much anyone would lose his job for sexually harassing (even if only once) a co-worker, but the Michigan Supreme Court decided that a six-month suspension was sufficient sanction for the judge's multi-year pattern of sexual harassment (note also how outrageous it was for the [judge's wife](https://eu.freep.com/story/news/local/michigan/2017/06/11/lenawee-county-judge/387542001/) to allegedly make her own statement "*calling the suspension draconian*", but that goes beyond the scope of your question). Not only was judge Iddings allowed to remain in judicial office after the suspension, but he was also allowed to seek re-election and received some [disreputable endorsements](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/2018/11/judge-carol-kuhnkes-imbecile.html) to that effect. He ultimately [lost his bench](http://www.lenconnect.com/news/20181108/sala-defeats-iddings-in-probate-judge-race), not by judicial sense of rectitude, but thanks to the electorate.

Comment: as a discussion of what the law should be, this belongs more eon politics.se rather than law.se. A discussion of what the law of negligence is, as it applies to a particular circumstance or profession, for example when can a physician be held negligent, would belong here on law.se. If a properly narrow question was asked, that is.

Comment: @DavidSiegel That is merely a pretext to keep downvoting answers, as I am not really discussing "*what the law should be*". The excerpts of *Parker v. State* and the MI Supreme Court opinion regarding judge Gregg Iddings (link provided in the 2nd-to-last paragraph) are examples of case law, that is, what the law *is* and/or how courts apply it. Citing the Code of Hammurabi serves as comparison between what the law is versus how it was.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I am actually intently pursuing information on why the Law is the way it is. I can explain it perfectly with Political Economics(The Politicians necessarily make the laws as such to be elected; they intently pursue their very own utility even if they thence harm their people). The very same reasons as tariffs on international trade.

Comment: @DavidSiegel even heard of lege ferenda?

Comment: @GeorgeN *Lex ferenda* or future law (a rather academic term) refers to proposed laws not enacted, or philosophic arguments about what the law should be. In short, it is entirely off-topic here on LAW.SE

Comment: @DavidSiegel https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lex#Declension https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fero#Etymology_5 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferendus#Latin I do not think an academic term is inherently bad. Is this not an Academic Q&A? If one must use academic terms so be it. It is neutral. What is LAW.SE about because Law studies Law in itself and not just the procedures. No matter who business minded one might try to make Law. Law is Linked to Philosophy,Economics,Psychology,Sociology,Politics, Histroy, Language. It is not a craft or a business but a science.

Comment: @GeorgeN See https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic This forum is for Q&A about what the current law is, including legal procedures. It is not for discussing what the law should be, or why it is as it is. And the law is not a science, except in the old sense in which any field of knowledge is a science. Law is a profession. The law is an institution in society. it is an organized but not fully consistent structure. It is indeed related to many fields, including the ones you list, but that does not mean that those broad areas are on-topic in this forum.

Comment: @DavidSiegel What is Legal Theory?

Answer (score 5):

> In the U.S are judges, attorneys, physicians, teachers, professors,
>   politicians, administrative officers liable for ordinary negligence?

In the U.S., judges, prosecuting attorneys and legislators have absolute immunity from civil liability (but not from criminal liability) for legislative and judicial acts in their official capacity.

Attorneys have absolute immunity from civil liability from some claims from some people (e.g. defamation claims from non-clients for statements made in connection with representing someone) and qualified immunity from civil liability from others (e.g. most claims of non-clients) for their acts as lawyers, but are liable to their clients for ordinary negligence.

Physicians are liable to their patients for ordinary negligence in the nature of medical malpractice. Some acts taken by physicians that would otherwise constitute false imprisonment or assault or homicide are excluded from the definition of those crimes.

Elected officials in the executive branch including mayors, law enforcement officers and the attorney general have qualified immunity from civil liability for their official non-judicial acts. This means that they are only liable for intentional violations of constitutional rights that are clearly established in the law. Subject to narrow exceptions (e.g. driving or medical malpractice) they are not liable for ordinary negligence.

It is hard to know what kind of liability is contemplated for teachers and professors or administrative officers to answer. The answer would not be the same for all kinds of claims. Teachers of minors generally have the same immunities as a parent with respect to the use of physical force towards their students in order to maintain order in the educational process. The liability of teachers and professors also depends upon whether they are employed by public or private institutions. Those in public institutions often have more protections from liability, but also have exposure to civil rights claims that those in private institutions are not. Contractual waivers can also influence liability in these circumstances.

Everyone has liability for ordinary negligence in their unofficial capacity and for many acts (e.g. driving a car) while on duty but not involving activities particular to their professional responsibilities.

> They are not employees or workers so that they could be reasonably
>   absolved for ordinary negligence.
>
> We expect employees to be obedient so they have no moral
>   responsibility, if we held them liable we would harm the market people
>   would be reluctutant to enter a contract of employeement.

In the private sector, employees are usually liable for ordinary negligence that they personally commit, even though the employer is also liable.

Judges are employees and arguably workers as well. And, for their non-judicial acts, judges have the same liability as every other employee for their ordinary negligence. For example, if a judge gets in a car accident while driving from one courtroom to another, and harms another through negligence, the judge has personal liability for the judge's ordinary negligence and the judicial branch has vicarious liability for the negligence of its employee, the judge.

> In all these of judges etc cases they receive more than enough
>   indenization for assuming responsibility.
>
> By freeing them from ordinary negligence we are making them negligent.
>
> Other than political economics why would the legislator free them from
>   such responsibility?

Analysis of why the law is the way it is, or what it should be, are really better suited for Politics.SE than for Law.SE. I discussion of the why's of judicial immunity is appropriate for Politics.SE. A discussion of "judges etc" is probably to broad for either forum.

Comment: By mistrial I mean judicial malpractice, otherwise(if they were not immune) culpable judicial misconduct.  Analysis of the law is actually what the science of Law does. If law was assumed to be just as it should and lawyers just "did" they just handled cases they put them through Law would be just business. A case would be nothing more than a transaction. It would not be a science but rather a simple business. Justice is just too important for society for it to be just a business. Lawyers should know the basics of mathematics,statistics,philosophy,linguistics,sociology and economy.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Law is not a science (and never has been, German protestations to the contrary notwithstanding) even though it often is more than just business. There are more than enough barriers to entry into the profession as it is.

Comment: So is it just another profession and not an important authority or service? Especially Judges. They study law too don't they? You see studying and penalties for negligence as barriers?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos In the U.S. about 99% of judges are experienced and successful and politically connected lawyers in a second career (while 1% are non-lawyers with no formal legal education except a few weeks of crash course in being a judge). Liability concerns are very different for judges and practicing attorneys. Lawyers are just another profession providing a valuable service just like other professions, more than a business, but the fewer there are, the less accessible the legal system is to the less affluent. It's harder to be a lawyer in the U.S. than in Europe (7 v 3-4 years of school).

Comment: Do you see studying and penalties for negligence as shameful barriers?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Who said anything about shame? The question is economics. If only a polymath genius can be a lawyer or judge, we won't have enough to do justice in the many cases that exist. In the judicial branch we acknowledge that some mistakes will be made an provide a remedy for mistakes in the form of an appeal rather than liability, and something like 5% of cases that go to trial are successfully appealed which would make it economically impossible for judges to practice law while defending so many collateral lawsuits (a judge may handle hundreds or thousands of cases a year).

Comment: So do we care about how they do their job or not? Should they serve justice on a whim? A lawyer should study logic, ethics, axiology, phenomenology, epistemology and aesthetics 6 philosophy modules real analysis 1 math module inferential and descriptive statistics 2 statistics modules principles of sociology and economic sociology 2 sociology modules principle of economic theory, general equilibrium, economics of crime  3 economics modules and Use of English 1 Linguistics module. 15 Modules is it economically inefficient for the society to fit 15 modules in their studying scedule?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos We largely regulate judges by determining who will be hired and by the process for their retention (most U.S. judges below the federal level don't serve for life). It rarely makes sense to mandate curricula for people who have typically finished their higher education a decade earlier. Lawyers in the U.S. have four years of general undergraduate education in non-law subjects of their choice and three years of law school after that plus bar exam preparation. U.S. lawyers have much more general education than those in Europe. This educational burden makes U.S. lawyers expensive.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Also, keep in mind that in the U.S., higher education is very expensive (typically $350K+ over seven years) much of which is financed with loans if a family doesn't have personal funds to pay for it. Increasing education requirements keep the poor and middle class out of the profession and also because it fights biological clocks, makes it harder for women who want to have children become lawyers and establish judicial careers after a decade or so as a lawyer. In contrast, in Europe, higher education is often free or heavily subsidized and only 3-4 years of school are needed.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos And, in Europe, a typical career path is to go straight from college to a junior judicial post (e.g. traffic court) and then working your way up, with no prior time as a prosecutor or private lawyer.

Comment: Actually in Europe Law school is 4 years. Universities' courses are 4 years for all courses except engineering and dentistry witch require a minimum of 5 and medicine with 6. Military training is mandatory. You need 6 months of internship to be given a chance for exams to enter the bar. And you "need" at least a graduate degree if you hope to get anywhere.  Higher education is not free. Mind the inflation. People's salaries are much lower so the prices will be equally low. Most European countries have less buying power per capita. Some countries subsidize higher education.

Comment: Greece for example does not even allow private universities. And this does not mean that the burden for the family of a student in Greece is less than the burden for the family of a student in U.S

Comment: You are wrong about going straight from univerity to a junior judicial post. You have to serve a long time as a lawyer in the bar. And judges actually study more that other lawyers. After law school, internship, bar exam, serving time as a lawyer you also have Judges' school a special course for judges and prosecutors. I am not questioning whether one law system is better than the other. What I am questioning is the way justice is served in both systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92287/discussion-between-ohwilleke-and-george-ntoulos).

Comment: I cannot see the chat.